# How to find a Magic Square of Squares (n^2)?

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics, magic-square

I am trying to find a magic square whose elements are distinct squares of natural numbers.

I have 200 solutions of 4 numbers, for each row or column of the magic square. But how would I combine them to 16 numbers whose sum is 8515, [one of possible sums in a magic square of squares](http://www.multimagie.com/English/SquaresOfSquares.htm#LE2)?

And how would we make a generalized program that works for any given numbers, and n x n.

```
import math
import time
from collections import Counter

def find_solutions(N):
    solutions = set()
    sqrt_N = int(math.isqrt(N))  # Calculate the square root of N
    for a in range(sqrt_N + 1):
        a_squared = a**2
        for b in range(sqrt_N + 1):  # Start from 0
            b_squared = b**2
            for c in range(sqrt_N + 1):  # Start from 0
                c_squared = c**2
                remaining = N - a_squared - b_squared - c_squared

                if remaining < 0:
                    break  # Stop if remaining is negative

                d = int(math.isqrt(remaining))
                d_squared = d**2

                if a_squared + b_squared + c_squared + d_squared == N and len({a, b, c, d}) == 4:
                    solutions.add(tuple(sorted([a, b, c, d])))

    return solutions

# Specify your value of N
N = 8515  # Change this to your desired value

# Print the result and execution time
solution_count = len(solutions)

if solution_count == 0:
    print(f"No solutions found for a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = {N}")
else:
    print(f"Number of unique solutions for a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = {N}: {solution_count}")

    # Calculate total occurrences for each number in the list of solutions
    total_counts = Counter([num for sublist in solutions for num in sublist])

    # Calculate percentages for each number
    total_solutions = sum(total_counts.values())
    number_percentages = {num: (count / total_solutions) * 100 for num, count in total_counts.items()}

    # Sort solutions by total percentage in descending order
    sorted_solutions = sorted(solutions, key=lambda solution: sum(number_percentages[num] for num in solution), reverse=True)

    # Print the results
    print("\nSolutions in Descending Order of Total Percentage:")
    print("{:<30} {:<10}".format("[a, b, c, d]", "Total Percentage"))
    for solution in sorted_solutions:
        total_percentage = sum(number_percentages[num] for num in solution)
        print("{:<30} {:<10.5f}%".format(str(solution), total_percentage))
```

Well i have been trying brute force, i have been trying different search algortihms but nothing works for me, and i just need to be over it. I have been trying graph theory, but it takes too much time. I even went as far as to imagine each values in the magic square of square as function cause it is like qudratic function f(x) = a^2 + k . And then somehow optimize it. But, it didn't work for me. I am requesting help from the community! Thanks.

*******************************UPDATE*****************************_______**

Thanks for all you guys questions. Now, i have updated it slightly, and now i want to find a solutions which is "faster."

Here was my idea, but i am stuck on as to how to even match it so it solves the magic square of square :

```
import math
import time
from collections import Counter

def find_solutions(N):
    solutions = set()
    sqrt_N = int(math.isqrt(N))  # Calculate the square root of N
    for a in range(sqrt_N + 1):
        a_squared = a**2
        for b in range(sqrt_N + 1):  # Start from 0
            b_squared = b**2
            for c in range(sqrt_N + 1):  # Start from 0
                c_squared = c**2
                remaining = N - a_squared - b_squared - c_squared

                if remaining < 0:
                    break  # Stop if remaining is negative

                d = int(math.isqrt(remaining))
                d_squared = d**2

                if a_squared + b_squared + c_squared + d_squared == N and len({a, b, c, d}) == 4:
                    solutions.add(tuple(sorted([a, b, c, d])))

    return solutions

# Specify your value of N
N = 8515  # Change this to your desired value

# Print the result and execution time
solution_count = len(solutions)

if solution_count == 0:
    print(f"No solutions found for a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = {N}")
else:
    print(f"Number of unique solutions for a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = {N}: {solution_count}")

    # Calculate total occurrences for each number in the list of solutions
    total_counts = Counter([num for sublist in solutions for num in sublist])

    # Calculate percentages for each number
    total_solutions = sum(total_counts.values())
    number_percentages = {num: (count / total_solutions) * 100 for num, count in total_counts.items()}

    # Sort solutions by total percentage in descending order
    sorted_solutions = sorted(solutions, key=lambda solution: sum(number_percentages[num] for num in solution), reverse=True)

    # Print the results
    print("\nSolutions in Descending Order of Total Percentage:")
    print("{:<30} {:<10}".format("[a, b, c, d]", "Total Percentage"))
    for solution in sorted_solutions:
        total_percentage = sum(number_percentages[num] for num in solution)
        print("{:<30} {:<10.5f}%".format(str(solution), total_percentage))
```

Comment: Your code looks like it's finding 4 squares that add up to N rather than having anything to do with magic squares. And what's 8515? That number doesn't appear in the link you give.

Comment: You can reduce your search to `a <= b <= c <= d`. All other solutions are permutations of these.

Comment: *"And how would we ..."*: I think that makes your question too broad. And as stated, your code snippet shows no attempt at creating a magic square.

Comment: Half way the page you linked to there is a formula for generating 4x4 squares with variable , so that gives you an infinite number of them.

Comment: Hi everybody, thanks for your questions. First of all, the number 8515 is if you look at the euler's square, and add all numbers from any rows, it adds up to 8515. Thinking of each value as functions could potentially be made into mathematical analysis?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when finding solutions for 4 numbers (a, b, c, d), you can introduce the constraint a < b < c < d into the search by adjusting the ranges. You don't need to check if some of the numbers are equal; you don't need to sort them, and you can arrange the solutions as a `list` and not a `set` (`list` is faster to append to).

```
def find_solutions(N):
    solutions = []
    sqrt_N = int(math.isqrt(N))  # Calculate the square root of N
    for a in range(0, sqrt_N):
        a_squared = a**2
        for b in range(a+1, sqrt_N):  # Start from a+1, not from 0
            b_squared = b**2
            for c in range(b+1, sqrt_N):  # Start from b+1, not from 0
                c_squared = c**2
                remaining = N - a_squared - b_squared - c_squared

                if remaining <= c_squared:
                    break  # Stop if remaining is too small

                d = int(math.isqrt(remaining))
                d_squared = d**2

                if a_squared + b_squared + c_squared + d_squared == N:
                    solutions.append((a, b, c, d))

    return solutions
```

To find a magic square, you should combine 4 row solutions, and check that the columns don't violate the magic-square conditions. A brute-force search could be something like this:

```
for a, b, c, d in solutions:
    for e, f, g, h in solutions:
        for i, j, k, l in solutions:
            for m, n, o, p in solutions:
                if (whatever):
                    # print the solution
```

To improve the performance of the search, you can do the iteration in a different order. There are a lot of constraints on the numbers in magic squares; the guideline is to check the constraints as close to the outer loop as possible. Changing the order of iteration makes it possible to apply constraints early.

I noticed that for each pair of adjacent numbers in a row of a magic square, the choice for the rest of them is very limited. For example, if there are 80 and 25 in a column or row, the other numbers are either 11 and 37 or 23 and 31 — only 4 possibilities (taking order into account)!

To take advantage of this, make a dictionary which says which possibilities exist for each pair of numbers.

```
poss = {}
for s in solutions:
    for a, b, c, d in itertools.permutations(s):
        if (a, b) not in poss:
            poss[(a, b)] = []
        poss[(a, b)].append((c, d))
```

Start searching upper-left 4 numbers. The constraints for them are that they should be different, and should appear in the list of column-solutions.

```
# a b * *
# c d * *
# * * * *
# * * * *
for a, b in poss:
    for e, f in poss:
        if a == e or a == f or b == e or b == f:
            continue
        if (a, e) not in poss or (b, f) not in poss:
            continue
```

Next, iterate through possible values of upper-right 4 numbers. The constraints on them are that they should be all different, and should appear in the list of column-solutions.

```
# a b c d
# e f g h
# * * * *
# * * * *
for a, b in poss:
    for e, f in poss:
        if a == e or a == f or b == e or b == f:
            continue
        if (a, e) not in poss or (b, f) not in poss:
            continue
        for c, d in poss[(a, b)]:
            for g, h in poss[(e, f)]:
                if len(set((a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h))) != 8:
                    continue
                if (c, g) not in poss or (d, h) not in poss:
                    continue
```

Next, iterate through possible values of lower-left 4 numbers. The constraints on them are that they should be all different, and should appear in the list of row-solutions.

```
# a b c d 
# e f g h
# i j * *
# m n * *
for a, b in poss:
    for e, f in poss:
        if a == e or a == f or b == e or b == f:
            continue
        if (a, e) not in poss or (b, f) not in poss:
            continue
        for c, d in poss[(a, b)]:
            for g, h in poss[(e, f)]:
                if len(set((a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h))) != 8:
                    continue
                if (c, g) not in poss or (d, h) not in poss:
                    continue
                for i, m in poss[(a, e)]:
                    for j, n in poss[(b, f)]:
                        if len(set((a, b, e, f, i, j, m, n))) != 8:
                            continue
                        if (i, j) not in poss or (m, n) not in poss:
                            continue
```

Finally, iterate over the rest of the numbers. Check all constraints on them.

```
# a b c d 
# e f g h
# i j k l
# m n o p
for a, b in poss:
    for e, f in poss:
        if a == e or a == f or b == e or b == f:
            continue
        if (a, e) not in poss or (b, f) not in poss:
            continue
        for c, d in poss[(a, b)]:
            for g, h in poss[(e, f)]:
                if len(set((a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h))) != 8:
                    continue
                if (c, g) not in poss or (d, h) not in poss:
                    continue
                for i, m in poss[(a, e)]:
                    for j, n in poss[(b, f)]:
                        if len(set((a, b, e, f, i, j, m, n))) != 8:
                            continue
                        if (i, j) not in poss or (m, n) not in poss:
                            continue
                        for k, o in poss[(c, g)]:
                            for l, p in poss[(d, h)]:
                                solution = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p)
                                if len(set(solution)) != 16:
                                    continue
                                if (k, l) not in poss[(i, j)] or (o, p) not in poss[(m, n)]:
                                    continue
                                # print the solution
```

As for larger dimensions of magic squares — I think this idea will work there too, but maybe you can find better ones.